# gnu parallel: combined use of --pipe and args

Tags: bash, gnu-parallel

using `--pipe -N<int>` I can send a given number of lines as an input of job started by `parallel`. But how can I accomplish to run several jobs with different arguments given with `:::` on each chunk?

Let's take this little input file:

```
A   B   C
D   E   F
G   H   I
J   K   L
```

Furthermore let's define to pipe every two line to a `parallel` job. And on them the command `cut -f<int>` should be executed with column number given as input arguments to parallel like `::: {1..3}`

So for the given example the output would look like this

```
A
D
B
E
C
F
G
J
H
K
I
L
```

I'v tried this command:

```
cat input.txt|parallel --pipe -N2 'cut -f{1}' ::: {1..3}
```

But the output is this:

```
A
D
I
L
```

What I'm missing?

fin swimmer

Answer (score 5):

This:

```
cat input.txt|parallel --pipe -N2 'cut -f{1}' ::: {1..3}
```

reads 2 records from each input source. It is more clear if you do:

```
$ cat input.txt|parallel --pipe -v -N2 'cut -f{}' ::: {1..3}
cut -f1  -f2
cut: only one type of list may be specified
Try 'cut --help' for more information.
cut -f3
I
L
```

GNU Parallel pairs each argument with a block. What you are looking for is more like `--tee` where every block is sent to every command. `--tee`, however, does not chop input into blocks, but sends all input to the command. So maybe we can combine the two:

```
doit() { parallel --pipe -N2 -v cut -f$@; }
export -f doit
cat input.txt|parallel --pipe --tee -v doit {} ::: {1..3}
```

Or you can flip the order (this is probably less efficient):

```
doit() { parallel -v --pipe --tee cut -f{} ::: {1..3}; }
export -f doit
cat input.txt|parallel --pipe -N2 -v doit
```

Remove `-v` when you are happy with what is being run.

`--tee` is very efficient (1-2 GBytes/s with `--pipe`, 2-3 GBytes/s with `--pipepart`), but it has the disadvantage, that it starts all jobs in parallel: So if you instead of {1..3} have 10000 values, then it will start 10000 processes.

Comment: Hello Ole, thanks for your detailed answer. I will play around next week with it.